# SQL Server Find What Jobs Are Running a Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to find out what jobs are using a certain stored procedure?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This will capture instances where the procedure is explicitly referenced in the job step:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(255) = N'procedure_name';

SET @s = QUOTENAME(@s, nchar(37));

SELECT job_name = j.name,
       s.step_id,
       s.step_name,
       j.date_created,
       j.date_modified
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s
  ON j.job_id = s.job_id
      WHERE s.command   LIKE @s
         OR j.name      LIKE @s
         OR s.step_name LIKE @s;
```

If it is called by something else that is called from the job, or the command is constructed with dynamic SQL, this might be a little more difficult to track down. Note also that if your procedure name can also appear naturally in other code, comments, etc. that it may produce false positives.

A much more elaborate and flexible search procedure that I updated last year:

- [A handy search procedure](https://sqlblog.org/2021/10/20/a-handy-search-procedure)

And even better is this module in [AMtwo](https://twitter.com/AMtwo)'s [DBA Database](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database):

- [dbo.Find_StringInModules](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database/blob/production/stored-procedures/dbo.Find_StringInModules.sql)

Comment: Slight modification to this:
`DECLARE @Search varchar(255)
SET @Search='searchstring'

SELECT j.name, s.step_id, s.step_name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s, msdb.dbo.sysjobs as j 
WHERE s.job_id = j.job_id
AND s.command LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'`