# How to check if running store procedure was triggered by job?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-agent-job

Is there a way to check within store procedure whether it was triggered by Job or using other methods i.e. SSIS, at hoc query etc?

There was similar question [SQL Server Find What Jobs Are Running a Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828733/sql-server-find-what-jobs-are-running-a-procedure)
but it just check job steps, but this is not what I need.

This is my scenario.

I have SP spDoSomethingImportant and this can be run by Job or i.e. user in database.

So within that SP I want to have a check if it was trigger by a job and get the name or Id of that job.

Comment: You can't do that as you are asking. But you can determine which user the connection was made from. Assuming you have a dedicated jobs user it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, there can be number of users that can run this SP directly, or it will be run on schedule (by Sql Agent - service account) so I will not be able to do it I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah I don't think so. Remember that sql server doesn't care about your jobs. All they really do is make a nice package that executes sql just like any other user. As such you can't tell what job invoked a step unless you put that information in the connection string. ApplicationName, UserName etc to help identify what is calling your procedures.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I guess I will have to add something like parameter where I can pass the job ID or name or something else that will help me trace what triggered given store procedure. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if you could use [CONTEXT_INFO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx) to help identify whether it came from fixed callers (agent, ssis, etc) and then by the absence of it being set, we can assume it's ad hoc?

Comment: If you can edit the stored procedure, maybe could you give it a [default = NULL] parameter that takes the `USER_NAME()` if null and then either return the proxy that ran the package, or alter the package to give a specific value such as "SSISpackageName"? It's a bit long winded but might give the info you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the following SPROC:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTME
AS

INSERT  INTO TEST_LOG
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE   session_Id = @@SPID

GO
```

I then ran it from SSMS. In `TEST_LOG`, the column Program_name is "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query"

I then created a job to run this SPROC. In `TEST_LOG`, the column Program_name is "SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0xCB393E8FF0E9D44485204D0100803469 : Step 1)"

So if you didn't want to pass a parameter to indicate if it's running as a job, I think you could figure it out from `sys.dm_exec_sessions.Program_name`

Comment: This might not be ideal solution and it may not work for everything but it should work for Job names. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following great advice from Robert Paulsen I have created simple solution to achieve this.

I have also used some code from this location to convert string to unique identifier. It was posted by Scott Pletcher. There is a function to get this uid from string.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1480606.aspx

Example code can look like this. There is a need for more checks as the code will not work if is not run by SQL Agent.

```
--Get Program Name
DECLARE @ProgramName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @StartOfJjobId INT
DECLARE @JobIdPrefix VARCHAR(30) = '(Job 0x'
SET @ProgramName = (SELECT Program_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_Id = @@SPID)
--If run by job it will returns something like this line below
--SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x5A9C063C3BDE5D41B4CBF86D4C1A82A5 Step 1)
SET @StartOfJjobId = CHARINDEX(@JobIdPrefix, @ProgramName) + LEN(@JobIdPrefix)

select name AS JobName from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = (SELECT CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 06, 2) + SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 04, 2) + 
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 02, 2) + SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 00, 2) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 10, 2) + SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 08, 2) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 14, 2) + SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 12, 2) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 16, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@ProgramName, @StartOfJjobId + 20,12) AS uniqueidentifier))
```